# jQuery add date to input, but only if it's empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I need to add current day and month to input fields, but only if they are empty. If fields have some data added, then it should not change that.

Here's the idea. Two fields, one for month and one for day. If input has no value, day and month are added, but if value is "anything" then it leaves it as it is. Day format should be 05, for month Jan, Feb, Mar. It can run on page load or with button, doesn't really matter to me.

Thanks

```
<input type="text" id="NewsDay" value="" />
<input type="text" value="" id="NewsMonth" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8N7n/

Comment: Have you tried anything except html-markup?

Comment: Are you talking about adding in current date on submission? You can use placeholders to hint a value to the user, or use PHP (Serverside) to create a default value for empty fields or Javascript to add a value to empty fields before submitting it.

Comment: @u_mulder I'm affraid not...i don't even know how to start, since js is really not my thing.

Comment: @StefanDunn It's like this. User is adding news and i wan't them to have field populated with date when adding news first time, but when editing news, fields should stay the same (they are saved to db on first save). It would be most simple to just ask user to fill it, but that will not work in most cases.

Comment: Then populate the fields with a conditional statement, `<?= (empty($dayFromDB))? date('d') : $dayFromDB; ?>`. Or using a Javascript alternative if you want to do it front-end (but beware that some users may have JS disabled).

Comment: PHP would be best option, but it's not possible in the templates...nevermid, i got answer and it works as temp solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c8N7n/4/)

```
var months = new Array(12);
months[0] = "Jan";
months[1] = "Feb";
months[2] = "Mar";
months[3] = "Apr";
months[4] = "May";
months[5] = "Jun";
months[6] = "Jul";
months[7] = "Aug";
months[8] = "Sep";
months[9] = "Oct";
months[10] = "Nov";
months[11] = "Dec";
var d = new Date();

var month = d.getMonth();

if($('#NewsDay').val() == "") {
    $('#NewsDay').val(d.getDate());
}
if($('#NewsMonth').val() == "") {
    $('#NewsMonth').val(months[month]);
}
```

A bit crude but works. Copied code from one of my [previous answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19138631/489512) I say crude because it doesn't consider timezones & day light savings and any other offsets.

Comment: Don't know if it's crude, but it does the job. Have to do some more tests....thanks

Comment: No worries about timezone and other fancy stuff, it's not important. I'm sorry my question was not more clear, but i really didn't know how to put it and research came back squat..so, thanks again.